# Having a unique span id in HTML using Jquery and Smarty

Tags: jquery, html, smarty

I have this question voting system on jQuery which perfectly works:

```
$(".q_upvote").click(function()
    {
        var vote = "vote_up";
        var question_id = this.id.split('_')[1];
        var votedata = "q_vote=" + vote+"&question_id="+question_id;
        $.ajax({                 
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'vote.php',
                data: votedata,
                success: function(vote_msg){
                   if($.trim(vote_msg) == 'ok')
                       {
                        $("#votenum").text( parseInt($("#votenum").text()) + 1 );                       }
                   else{
                       }
                }
           });
    }
)
```

And this is it's HTML part :

```
<p><span id="votenum">{$question_vote}</span> 
<a id="upvote_{$qid}" class="q_upvote" href="#"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>
```

I want to do the same thing with answers too. I wrote this :

```
$(".a_upvote").click(function()
    {
        var vote = "vote_up";
        var answer_id = this.id.split('_')[1];
        votedata = "q_vote=" + vote+"&answer_id="+answer_id;
        $.ajax({                 
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'vote2.php',
                data: votedata,
                success: function(vote_msg){
                alert(vote_msg)
                   if($.trim(vote_msg)== 'ok')
                       {
                        $("#answervotes").text( parseInt($("#answervotes").text()) + 1 );
                        }
                   else{
                       }
                }
           });
    }
)
```

and this is it's HTML part :

```
{if isset($allanswers) eq True} {section name=res loop=$allanswers}</p>
<div text-align:center;><p> {$allanswers[res].answer_text} </p>
{if isset($smarty.session.username) eq True}
<p><span id = "answervotes">{$allanswers[res].answer_total_rate}</span>
<a id="upvote_{$allanswers[res].answer_id}" class="a_upvote" href="#""><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>
<a id="downvote_{$allanswers[res].answer_id}" class="a_downvote" href="#" "><i class="icon-thumbs-down" ></i></a></p>
{else}
<p>{$allanswers[res].answer_total_rate}</p>
{/if}
```

My problem is if there are several answers and users upvote nth answer, only the vote of the first number changes, the vote of nth answer doesn't change. I think I need to make answervotes unique somehow but I don't know how. How can I fix this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you make your `span` `id` unique. by doing the following.

`<p><span id = "answervotes{$allanswers[res].answer_id}">{$allanswers[res].answer_total_rate}</span>`

Then in your call

```
$(".a_upvote").click(function()
{
    var vote = "vote_up";
    var answer_id = this.id.split('_')[1];
    votedata = "q_vote=" + vote+"&answer_id="+answer_id;
    $.ajax({                 
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'vote2.php',
            data: votedata,
            success: function(vote_msg){
               if($.trim(vote_msg)== 'ok')
                   {
                    $("#answervotes" + answer_id).text( parseInt($("#answervotes"  + answer_id).text()) + 1 );
                    }
               else{
                   }
            }
       });
}
```

)

Answer (score 1):

what i could see here is you have multiple ids with the same name `answervotes` since this is created in loop (if i am not wrong) so it is updating the first one...

you better change your ids to class or make it unique..since having multiple elements with same id is invalid and  may gives you problem(the problem that you are facing now)...

try this (changing id to class here)

```
<p><span class= "answervotes">{$allanswers[res].answer_total_rate}</span>
```

and your jquery

```
$(".a_upvote").click(function()
{
    var $this=$(this);  //<--here
    var vote = "vote_up";
    var answer_id = this.id.split('_')[1];
    votedata = "q_vote=" + vote+"&answer_id="+answer_id;
    $.ajax({                 
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'vote2.php',
            data: votedata,
            success: function(vote_msg){
            alert(vote_msg)
               if($.trim(vote_msg)== 'ok')
                   {
                    $this.siblings(".answervotes").text( parseInt($("#answervotes").text()) + 1 );  //<----here
                    }
               else{
                   }
            }
       });
}
)
```

used `siblings()` since your `answervotes` span and `upvote` a is inside the same parent `<p>`